# Define Source port of tcp socket SOCK_STREAM

Tags: c, sockets, port

i want to define the sourceport(localport) of this socket connection -- some help plox xD

```
if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
    {
        continue;
    }
    // Set it in nonblocking mode
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);
    // Set up address to connect to
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if (targs[i].netmask < 32)
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ntohl(targs[i].addr) + (((uint32_t)rand_next()) >> targs[i].netmask));
    else
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = targs[i].addr;
    if (dport == 0xffff)
        addr.sin_port = rand_next() & 0xffff;
    else
        addr.sin_port = htons(dport);           
    connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
    usleep(1000000);
    start_recv = time(NULL);
```

Comment: Use `bind()` to select the local port.

Comment: Why? This is a really bad idea as the socket will not be available till the time-wait has expired.

Comment: @Barmar thanks i will try this

Comment: @RowanSmith that exactly what i need to keep the socket open until i finish him

Comment: @Barmar looks like am newbie with c .. can you please give me an example

Comment: Show what you tried and I'll show how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
// Hard code src port address
address.sin_port=htons(9999);
// Bind to port - warning check return code for failure
bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&address,sizeof(address));
// Connect         
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));
```